# Insert a delay of a few seconds in SSJS script after a function call

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, automationstudio

**Use case**: Send emails based on personlization data of a few records using SSJS script.

I have an email that will pull personlization data of off a non sendable Data Extension. The email will pull the data from 1 st row and send that personlized email to a separate 100 records. Next it will pull the data from 2nd row, send that personlized email to the same 100 records and so on.. Instead of having to create 10 different emails, I am planning to create a single email with the loop counter maintained in the script. Find the script below:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var totalCount = Platform.Function.Lookup('Non Sendable DE with personal data','no_of_annivs_today','lookupKey','1');
var i = 1;
var status;

function sendEmail()
{
    var esd = Send.Definition.Init('Test');
    status = esd.Send();

}

try
{
        do
        {
            sendEmail();

            --Insert delay here
            var increaseRowCountBy1 = i+1;
            DataExtension.Init('Non Sendable DE with personal data').Rows.Update({getRow:increaseRowCountBy1},["lookupKey"],["1"]);


        } while(i<=totalCount);

}

catch(error)

{
    DataExtension.Init('Non Sendable DE with personal data').Rows.Update({Error:"Yes"},["lookupKey"],["1"]);

}
```

The problem I am facing here is that by the time the first email is initialized and sent, the loop variable "i" is already at the max value and the only email sent is the last record in that non sendable DE. I need a delay of 20-30 seconds so that the previous email is sent before the loop counter variable is increased.

AMPScript in the email:

```
        set @i  = Lookup('Non Sendable DE with personal data','getRow','lookupKey',1)
```

**Solutions explored**:
 1. setTimeout() : Not viable since Marketing Cloud does not support this function.
 2. status variable: I tried using the status variable to hold the loop variable from increment but the variable is getting assigned "EmailsendDefinition Performed" status before all the emails are actually sent.

Let me know if the question is unclear or the strategy I am trying to implement is not viable for the use case. Any help is appreciated.